# Variable JSON values / methods inside JSON

Tags: javascript, json, methods

My website has a functionality of synthesizing speech from preset text. I wanted to diversify it to include multiple languages. Hence, I chose to move the texts to JSON voiceOutputs.

```
{
    "english": {
        "actionStarted": "Action has started",
        "success": "Success",
        "error": "Error occured",
        "goodNight": "Good Night"
    },
    "japanese": {
        "actionStarted": "アクションが始まりました",
        "success": "成功しました",
        "error": "エラーが発生しました",
        "goodNight": "おやすみなさい"
    }
}
```

And I can use these texts by

```
voiceOutputs.[getCookie("voiceLang")].actionStarted;
```

How do I revamp my variable dependent texts into JSON structure as the sentence pattern differs with languages.

Eg.

```
"Good bye " + variableforName
variableForName + "おやすみなさい。"
```

I can't call "goodBye" and "おやすみなさい" directly as I want to create a generalized version of output and I need a proper word pattern depending on language.

Work-arounds: 
1. Using a function (easy but not optimized and takes a lot of work)

```
function goodNight(variableForName) {
    if (getCookie("voiceLang") == "japanese") {
        return variableForName+voiceOutputs.[getCookie("voiceLang")].goodNight;
    }
    else if (getCookie("voiceLang") == "english") {
            return voiceOutputs.[getCookie("voiceLang")].goodNight + " " + variableForName;
    }
```

2. Methods inside voiceOutputs JSON:

Is it possible???

Comment: Here are a couple L10N resources you can draw from: http://www.localeplanet.com, https://github.com/eligrey/l10n.js/

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). If you have an object or array, then you have an object or array, full stop. JSON format is a *method of representing an object in a string*, like `const myJSON = '{"foo":"bar"}'`. If there are no strings, serialization, or deserialization involved, then JSON is not involved either.

Comment: Point of the above is - I don't see anything JSON-specific in your question, do you *really* need your code to be JSON compatible (with serialization and deserialization), or can there be other things in the data as well, such as functions?

Comment: @CertainPerformance you are right. There is nothing JSON specific. However, the kind of utility that I need is too laborious and disorganized with functions. If you have any other organised data structure that I can use, please suggest. And if the title of the question bugs you, I am ready to change that as well. My motive is to get my program going and am stuck with not a lot of smart ways to move ahead.

Comment: Just trying to figure out the question, it's OK. I don't think functions would be disorganized at all - for example, `{ english: { goodNight: n => \`Good bye ${n}\` }, japanese: { goodNight: n => \`${n} おやすみなさい。\` }}`. That said, a template like in the answer below is simpler in most cases

Comment: Hahaha, this was exactly that I wanted. I just mistyped a few things and thought methods were not allowed in JSON. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a library for string formats (I do not know of any solid ones, please edit my answer or post your own), but you could also just use Vanilla Javascript's `String.prototype.replace` Combined with a character pattern you expect not to be seen in the same string otherwise

E.g.

```
"Good bye {{%name}}";
"{{%name}}おやすみなさい。";
```

You can then use both the same way, by calling `.replace('{{%name}}', nameVariable)`